# How to write a correct multiple-process server program via python3 asyncio reuse_port?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I intend to write a multiple-process server program via python3+asyncio, and I found there is a parameter named 'reuse_port' in AbstractEventLoop.create_server, it looks like what I wanted.

So I wrote some code, I use multiprocessing to create some processes, each process create an asyncio event loop, and all of these processes listen on a same port.

I thought these processes would be work together, to respond requests, but when I test this server program, I found there is only one process respond my request all the time.

So why the others processes doesn't respond requests?
Is there any BUGS in my code?

OSX10.11 + PYTHON3.5.2

***server:***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import multiprocessing
import asyncio
import socket

tcp_listen_port = 44330


class Listener:
    def __init__(self, protocol, listen_port, listen_host='localhost'):
        self._protocol = protocol
        self._listen_port = listen_port
        self._listen_host = listen_host
        self._loop = None
        self._server = None
        self._pid = os.getpid()

    def run(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        coro = self._loop.create_server(
            self._protocol,
            host=self._listen_host,
            port=self._listen_port,
            family=socket.AF_INET,
            reuse_port=True
        )

        self._server = self._loop.run_until_complete(coro)

        print('Listener Server on {}, pid {}'.format(
            self._server.sockets[0].getsockname(),
            self._pid
            ))
        self._loop.run_forever()

    def close(self):
        self._server.close()
        self._loop.run_until_complete(self._server.wait_closed())
        self._loop.close()


class ProtocolEcho(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        data = 'hello python asyncio from pid {}\r\n\r\n'.format(os.getpid()).encode()
        self.transport.write(data)
        self.transport.close()


def create_tcp_srv(listen_port):
    listener = Listener(ProtocolEcho, listen_port)
    try:
        listener.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        listener.close()


def main():
    cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    srvproclist = list()
    for i in range(cpu_count):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=create_tcp_srv,
            args=(tcp_listen_port,)
            )
        srvproclist.append(p)

    for proc in srvproclist:
        proc.start()

    for proc in srvproclist:
        proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***client***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os
import asyncio
import multiprocessing

async def req():
    connect = asyncio.open_connection('localhost', 44330)
    reader, writer = await connect

    writer.write('hello'.encode('utf-8'))
    await writer.drain()

    while True:
        line = await reader.readline()

        if line == b'\r\n':
            break

        print('proc {} recv {}'.format(os.getpid(), line.decode()))

    writer.close()


def begin_test():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [req() for i in range(10)]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()


plist = list()
for i in range(4):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=begin_test
        )
    plist.append(p)

for proc in plist:
    proc.start()

for proc in plist:
    proc.join()
```

The client output like this:

```
proc 72319 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72318 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72319 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72320 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72321 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72319 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72318 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72320 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72321 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72318 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72320 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
proc 72321 recv hello python asyncio from pid 72310
```

The last number '72310' is the server process pid who respond my request, so I thought there is only one process is working. But why...

Answer (score 0):

It takes quite a bit of work to get any program to do more than one thing at a time. You are creating one server with one never-ending process and haven't guided the program with callbacks (i.e. connection_made(), data_received(), etc). It's a simple fix, though, with the use of coroutines.

Simply put, it doesn't look like you have any events that invoke additional callbacks.

Implementing coroutines in your script will be a breeze as it looks like you are returning the same string for each process. All you gotta do is wrap each function (process) in a coroutine decorator(@asyncio.coroutine) and then set up the coroutine program with how you see fit.

Check [this](http://www.andy-pearce.com/blog/posts/2016/Jul/the-state-of-python-coroutines-asyncio-callbacks-vs-coroutines/) out. It's a great article on asyncio. Asyncio is getting a lot  of hype right now because it's making writing programs that do multiple things at the same time a LOT easier.

The implementation of 'yield from' is particularly awesome.

note: I would have put this in comments, but I don't have the street cred yet. One day....